# Installing bigdesk in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to install bigdesk in ElasticSearch, I downloaded the plugin and copied it uncompressed in the plugin directory

When I try to access to http://localhost:9200/_plugin/bigdesk I just see a white page.
I installed Marvel as well and I didn't have any problem.
I read the documentation in ES and it doesn't say to do anything else to install a new plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to enable JSONP in your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file.

```
http.jsonp.enable: true
```

Also make sure to append a slash at the end of the URL

```
http://localhost:9200/_plugin/bigdesk/
                                     ^
                                     |
                              add slash here
```

I've caught myself wondering, too, a few times because of this.

**UPDATE**

Since you've installed the plugin manually, make sure to unzip the package in the `/plugins/bigdesk/_site` folder since this is a site plugin.

Comment: I activated and restarted it and it doesn't work... just a white page.

Comment: Can you open the developer tools of your browser and check if you see some JS error in the console?

Comment: Yes, I tried as well with the last slash and there aren't errors in javascript. It just doesn't show anything.

Comment: Can you tell which version of ES you're using? Also when ES starts do you see `bigdesk` mentioned in the logs in the list of sites plugin, like here: `loaded [], sites [bigdesk, head, HQ, kopf, migration]` ?

Comment: I'm using 1.6.0, not, I just see marvel... I have checked the directory plugins and it seams everything right. There is two directories marvel and bigdesk

Comment: Can you remove the bigdesk folder and try to install with `bin/plugin --install lukas-vlcek/bigdesk` instead? I think that's the reason as it is a site plugin and its content shall be moved inside the `_site` sub-folder. Since you installed it manually, it might not be the case.

Comment: I move the directory plugin/bigdesk to plugin/bigdesk/_site and it works. I can't use the plugin command because I can't connect to internet from that machine, so I have to download the code from another machine and copy it by FTP.

Comment: Great then, it works! I've updated the answer to better reflect what the problem was.